# What is the default deadline in the Search API?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting Deadline errors with Search API calls -- what's the default RPC deadline referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass#Index_get) and elsewhere (as well as the format... milliseconds, seconds, etc)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same RPC deadline for all other APIs. At the current time the maximum value you use in your calls have to be smaller than the timeout value for other App Engine APIs that you use to make the call (URLFetch, for example).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) you may find more information about dealing with those errors